# Swift Regex: Remove numbers embedded inside words in a String

Tags: swift, regex, string, algorithm, filter

**Goal**: Remove numbers embedded inside a string.

**Example**: `let testString = "5What's9 wi3th this pro9ject I'm try905ing to build."`

**Desired Output**: `testString = "5What's9 with this project I'm trying to build"`

**What I've Tried**:

```
let resultString = testString
.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\b[:digit:]\\b", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
// fails, returns string as is

let resultString = testString
    .replacingOccurrences(of: "(\\d+)", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
// fails, returns all numbers removed from string.. close

let resultString = testString
    .replacingOccurrences(of: "[0-9]", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
// removes all numbers from string.. close
```

How can we remove numbers that are inside of words only?

Comment: You state that numbers should be removed from the string but it appears you only want to remove numbers that are inside of words. If you mean the latter you should clarify your question.

Comment: It was the latter, updated the question to be clarified like you have it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try doing a regex replacement on the following pattern:

```
(?<=\S)\d+(?=\S)
```

This matches only numbers surrounded on both sides by non whitespace characters.  Updated code:

```
let resultString = testString
    .replacingOccurrences(of: "(?<=\\S)\\d+(?=\\S)", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
```

Comment: Intersting, so it's ?<= 
means = Look-behind assertion. True if the parenthesized pattern matches text preceding the current input position, with the last character of the match being the input character just before the current position. Does not alter the input position.

Then, \\S means = match a non-white space character

So between matching non space white characters we filter the number between characters with \\d+ between captures groups..

Nicely done!  Thank you!!  Life saver.

Comment: @ScottW Yes, you described the regex correctly, so I won't add a deeper explanation, other than to say that `(?=\S)` _asserts_ that a non whitespace character follows, but it does not _match_ that character.  So the only thing my pattern actually _matches_ is `\d+`, the digits.

Comment: Please note that this answer fails if there is punctuation, a comma for example, after a digit at the end of a word. For example, if the string contained something like `word9, blah` then this answer results in `word, blah` when I believe the answer should not remove the digit since it's not inside a word. Maybe? What does the OP say?

Comment: @HangarRash Then we can match on `(?<=[^\s,;.?!])\d+(?=[^\s,;.?!])`

Comment: Yes, the answer should not remove the digit since it's not inside of a word.

Comment: But consider: `What'9s` which should become `What's` ... removal is not as simple as it may seem.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen yes that edge case is definitely an issue.  Like "10.6 billion" it converts to "106 billion" which isn't correct.  Not sure how to exclude punctuation from the rule..